# Question shows as - modified by Community

Tags: discussion, community-user, bump

Please have a look

[image]

It indicates that the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829/how-do-i-detect-if-a-function-is-available-during-jnlp-execution) is modified by Community . But there is no signs of Community modificaton . Is it normal as per [Community profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is *"modified"* and *"edited"* are 2 different terms. It shouldn't appear on the question's page.
This is the periodic auto-bumps. The community user [bumps questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped/48579#48579) with a lot of views.
[Related from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177726/why-has-every-question-on-webmasters-been-modified-by-community).

Here is [official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-%E2%99%A6-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511) about why is it happen:

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).

And [one more related from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/anomalous-community-user-activity).